# NSPageController resizing and snapshots

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSPageController in book mode with two pages and each contains an NSTableView. If I start my application and resize it vertically and then swipe to the other page the snapshot used in the swipe animation is of the NSTableView before the resize. This view swiping in only covers part of the previous view and this looks terrible. Is it possible to get the NSPageController to invalidate the snapshots when the view is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PictureSwiper](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/samplecode/PictureSwiper/Introduction/Intro.html) example does exactly this by setting the frame of the view whenever the window is resized. However, you need to have your layout/resize constraints set. Whenever the view size changes, the constraints will cause NSPageController's view objects to be resized as well. If you're doing something unique with your view layout/size, you will need to manually resize as in the example linked.

Also, snaphots are generated on-the-fly. From the `arrangedObjects` method documentation of `NSPageController`:

> The delegate will be asked for snapshots as they are needed.

And this is useful to keep in mind:

> When using the book mode, if `pageController.view` is layer backed, live layers are used during transition instead of snapshots.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because the NSPageController caches a snapshot of the view and uses that for the animation.

Comment: I've edited my response to link to the developer example that does what you're looking for.

Comment: I had seen and read all this and couldn't get the layer backed changed to work but it does now. Thanks!

Comment: @DalmazioBrisinda do you know how this can be done using autolayout on story board? I'm having the same issue.